# BeyondCompare Script : report of compare folder not display folder difference

Tags: directory, difference, beyondcompare3

I compare two folders with a BeyondCompare(v3) script and generate a report. In the report file there is the missing file (for exemple) notify but not the missing folder!
Any idea for add in the report the missing folder ?

Thx!

This is my script :

```
# Set up basic comparison features.
criteria timestamp:2sec
# Filter out log files.
filter "-*.log"
# Load first comparison.
load %1 %2
# Compare files with timestamp differences.
select newer.files older.files
# Generate a report of the differences.
folder-report layout:summary options:display-mismatches output-to:%3
```

This is my report:
    Folder Compare
    Produced: 28/08/2015 17:32:55

```
Mode:  Differences
Filters:  -*.log
Left base folder: C:\Users\Desktop\essaiBeyondC\Project1
Right base folder: C:\Users\Desktop\essaiBeyondC\Project2

Left Orphan Files (0)  Size Modified
------------------------------------

Right Orphan Files (0) Size Modified
------------------------------------

Left Newer Files (0)   Size Modified
------------------------------------

Right Newer Files (0)  Size Modified
------------------------------------

Differences Files (0)  Size Modified
------------------------------------

Unscanned Folders
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please don't answer in comments. Please post an answer. And it is ok to answer own questions.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: Remove in the script select `newer.files older.files` and write `expand all` and after `select all` .

You see in the report : `Right Orphan Files (3) Size Modified -------------------------------------------------- dossierA\titi.c 8 10/02/2015 14:38:54 dossierA\toto.c 4 11/05/2015 11:18:59`